# Conjugating (the product of) simultaneously diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B$ be invertible and simultaneously diagonalizable matrices. I want to conjugate the matrix $B$ by some invertible matrix $P$. It is not always the case that there exists some invertible matrix $Q$ such that
$$A P B P^{-1} = Q A B Q^{-1}.$$
Can we characterize the matrices for which there **does** always exist such a $Q$? Possibly for a fixed $A$?